# What causes blue artifacts when viewing an image in Camera Raw or Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, artifacts, error

I'm getting random blue artifacts, I have tried different monitors, monitor recalibration, sRGB, and I've tried running it on CPU (not the GPU). No luck yet soon as I open it in ANY other program it seems fine. Just does it in camera raw. So far I have only seen this on JPEGs but I'm not sure about other file types.

[image: Error]

Comment: This looks like it is highlighting where image is under exposed (and detail will be lost) for you. You can turn this off  by clicking on the upper left triangle on the histogram display in Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark as sorted soon as I can in 10 mins. I feel so stupid 

Comment: Except you can't because John decided to write his answer in the wrong place.

Comment: Haha Fair play 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The blue and red highlights in **Adobe Camera Raw** or **Adobe Lightroom** are called the **Shadow/Highlight clipping warnings**. They are indications of shadow or highlight areas that are *lacking detail*, meaning they have gone completely black or completely white.

They can be turned on and off using the triangles in the upper corners of the histogram.

Whether or not this is a bad thing is dependent upon whether those areas of the image should be completely black or completely white. Typically you don't want too much of either. Some things like lights or the sun may always clip.

These areas should be checked after making adjustments to exposure, shadows, hightlights, whites, blacks, etc. as each of those adjustments will have an impact on thise clipping levels.

Answer (score 3):

That's the shadow warning of ACR. You also have a highlight warning, which is red.
They indicate black resp. white parts of your image, which are likely under or over exposed.

You can toggle them by clicking on the little triangles top left and right of your histogram.

Also, you can see them increasing or decreasing when you play with the exposure sliders. Usually, you'll want to minimize those parts of the image by "pulling them in" with the exposure controls, except for specular highlights etc.

Comment: "...except for specular highlights etc." Well, and pure blacks that you want to be pure black.

Answer (score 1):

Those blue areas are indications from ACR that those pixels are underexposed. If you click on two triangles on the top of histogram you will switch this on and off (left for underexposure, right for overexposure). The same can be done by pressing u and o letters